# Bypass comment validation for SOME anonymous users, based on the provided email address?

Tags: 7, comments, users

In the case of a low traffic blog (for instance), that only accepts anonymous comments (no user registration) and manually validates them before publishing them, would it be possible to have a sort of internal white list for trusted email addresses (in the comment "email" field)?

The idea would be that comments using one of those addresses would be published immediately, without requiring validation.

(Obviously the email addresses of the commenters are not visible to the visitors.)

Is there a module for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Comment Trust](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_trust) module in order to **auto-approve** comments from **trusted** visitors.

> Comment Trust auto-approves comments by users with previously-approved
>   comments. It rewards trusted commenters with immediate approvals,
>   while requiring you to approve the comments by new visitors. Works for
>   both anonymous and authenticated users.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try it out. That looks exactly like what I was looking for.

Comment: Looks great. Can you confirm if it plays nice with Mollom?

Comment: I didn't use it with Mollom so couldn't confirm, unfortunately.

Comment: The module doesn't have any setting to whitelist some email address; it has the setting to blacklist email addresses, which is the one set on _Email addresses to never auto-approve_. Wasn't this one of the requirements made from @s427?

Comment: Instead of adding duplicate answers to multiple questions, please tailor to the answer for the question or flag as a duplicate.  Thanks.

Comment: @kiamlaluno : for me it was a suggestion more than a requirement (*"a sort of internal white list"*). The purpose of my question was to find a way to make validation easier (and improve user experience for frequent commenters) by auto-approving comments based on some rules. This module definitely does that, and in a way that is probably easier than having to manually fill and maintain a white list, so it's fine for me. (Was not aware that my question was a duplicate, sorry if it's the case.)

Answer (score 3):

Make a rule with event after saving a new comment. Then make a view with the list of emails which should be bypassed. Compare this with the current email of the user, if there is a match publish the comment on the node.
The comparing can be done with views + vbo and the rules action: Load a list of entity objects from a VBO View.combined with a loop statement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I would have hoped for something a little more straightforward. ^^

Comment: If you mean a more straightforward solution I cannot give. If you mean a a more straightforward explanation of this solution then I can do that. pls let me know

Comment: Yeah I meant a more straightforward solution (via a module or something like that). I appreciate your suggestion though. :)